# Set CreatedById Field in Apex Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, id, test-setup

I have created a trigger on the Account object that is validated only if the records are being created by an **non-admin account**.

In order to test this functionality I would have to set the `createdbyid`field in the test class, but when trying to do this I get the error:

> Field is not writeable: Account.CreatedById

I know that for the `CreatedDate` field, even though normally is **not writable** it can be changed in a test environment.

Is the same functionality available for `CreatedById` field?

If not, are there any other workarounds that would allow me to test this scenario?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Couldn't you use the runAs method to make the code execute as a non Admin user?

Comment: you can set created date using `Test.setCreatedDate(a.Id, DateTime.newInstance(2012,12,12));` in test class check sprint 16 release notes  http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_apex_tests.htm#rn_apex_tests_setcreateddate

Comment: @Ratan I know that about CreatedDate, but what about createdByid?

Comment: @MarcZaharescu you can use system.RunAs so you can insert your record in other user's context so salesforce will set the createdBYId for us.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
User u = new User();
//put the user details you want for this user.
insert u;

System.runAs(u) {
 /* your record insert here */
 insert Account;
}
```

The account will have the createdById set as the User u;

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to accomplish this.

See this link: [Setting system protected fields for test code coverage](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000181873&language=en_US)

It says:

> There are 2 ways in which you can set system protected fields for test
> code coverage:
>
> a) Using Test.loadData()
>
> b) Using JSON.deserialize()

I would prefer the 2nd method.

**Edit:**

As already said in comments if you only want to execute the class under any given profile you can directly use `System.runAs()` method.